# Error on Add file to deploy in Android, with firemonkey delphi Xe7

Tags: android, delphi, deployment, firemonkey

Which file I manage the deploy Itemns to remove/add manually my database? When I click add file on tool bar (Second button), and select the sqlite file on explorer, I receive an exception below.

It was working very well, and I changed many times the database version before.
But now, I delete the sqlite file and can't submit the file again.

I hope to delete some file on explorer to reset the deploy list. Somebody can help-me?

ps: I restarted delphi and also the windows.
[image: Error on Add sqlite file]

Comment: I found the file `ProjectName.deployproj`. The file has a xml structure with all icons, database and ini specification. I change the file manually but didn't fence the error. I got that the error just occur when I add a filename found in xml. But when I click delete on deploy windows, It don't removes the file. Like has another reference I can not change manually. Some idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the file ProjectName.deployproj. The file has a xml structure with all icons, database and ini specification. I change the file manually but didn't fence the error. I got that the error just occur when I add a filename found in xml. But when I click delete on deploy windows, It don't removes the file. Like has another reference I can not change manually. Some idea? Thanks in advance.